# Oracle SQL data modification

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like the one shown below:

```
 RowID |  ID |    col    | Label  |  
-----------------------------------
   1   |  1  |    Bad    |    N   |  
-----------------------------------
   2   |  1  | Very Good |    N   |  <---|
 -----------------------------------
   3   |  1  |Super Good |    N   |  <---| Either Label to be 'Y' (Contain 'Good')
-----------------------------------
   4   |  1  |  Too Bad  |    Y   |  <---$ Need this one to be 'N' (Contain 'Bad')
-----------------------------------
   5   |  2  | F*** Good |    N   | 
-----------------------------------
   6   |  2  | So Good   |    Y   | 
-----------------------------------
   7   |  2  | Really Bad|    Y   |  <---$ Need both to be 'N' (Contain 'Bad')
-----------------------------------
   8   |  2  |    Bad    |    Y   |  <---$ 
-----------------------------------
   9   |  3  |    Good   |    N   | 
-----------------------------------
   10  |  3  |    Good   |    Y   | 
-----------------------------------
   11  |  3  |  Bad Bad  |    N   |
```

`col` has two types of content which can be distinguished by key word `Good` and `Bad`. And `RowID` **does** **not** exist in my real table. Here I just use `RowID` for better description of my problem.

#### My goal:

For each group of the same `ID`, I want to change all `Label` of the `Bad` related rows to `N` (if there is any `Y`), and change the `Label` of at least one row whose `col` contains `Good` to `Y` (if all associated `label` are `N`)

#### For example:

For the group where `ID` = `1` (`RowID`=`1` to `4`), I want `Label` of `RowID` = `4` to be `N` instead of `Y` while change the `Label` of either `RowID` = `2` or `RowID` = `3` to `Y`.

For the group where `ID` = `2` (`RowID`=`5` to `8`), since `RowID`=`6` is already `Y` I just want to put the `Label` of both `RowID`=`7` and `8` to `N`.

For the group where `ID` = `3` (`RowID`=`9` to `11`), since the `Label` of `RowID`=`10` is `Y` and `RowID`=`11` is `N`. I do not need to modify this group.

I was thinking about using cursor in PL SQL but it should be very inefficient... after all I have 1.8 billion rows... Could anyone please show me how to write this in ORACLE SQL? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this gets the result you want:

```
select t.*,
  case when col like '%Bad%' then 'N'
       when max(case when col like '%Good%' then label else 'N' end)
         over (partition by id) = 'Y'
       then label
       when row_number()
         over (partition by id, case when col like '%Good%' then 'Y' end order by null) = 1
         then 'Y'
       else label
  end as new_label
from your_table t
order by rn;

        RN         ID COL        LABEL NEW_LABEL
---------- ---------- ---------- ----- ---------
         1          1 Bad        N     N        
         2          1 Very Good  N     Y        
         3          1 Super Good N     N        
         4          1 Too Bad    Y     N        
         5          2 F*** Good  N     N        
         6          2 So Good    Y     Y        
         7          2 Really Bad Y     N        
         8          2 Bad        Y     N        
         9          3 Good       N     N        
        10          3 Good       Y     Y        
        11          3 Bad Bad    N     N
```

(I'm not using `rn`, I've just left that in as a dummy column for ordering the result set).

This picks 'N' for any value containing Bad; otherwise it's a Good value, and if any Good value for the ID is already Y then the flags for all Good values for that ID are left alone; otherwise a semi-random Good value is set to Y.

Updating/merging your table based on this will be difficult as there isn't a single key to correlate against, at least in what you've shown, unless - maybe - the values are unique within an ID. Or there is another key column you haven't shown.

---

> I do have a unique ID column (using sys_guid())

You can use that in a merge, and to make the choice of which of rows 2 and 3 become Y slightly less arbitrary:

```
merge into your_table target
using (
  select t.*,
    case when col like '%Bad%' then 'N'
         when max(case when col like '%Good%' then label else 'N' end)
           over (partition by id) = 'Y' then label
         when row_number()
           over (partition by id, case when col like '%Good%' then 'Y' end
             order by guid_col) = 1 then 'Y'
         else label
    end as new_label
  from your_table t
) source on (source.guid_col = target.guid_col)
when matched then
  update set target.label = source.new_label
  where target.label is null or target.label != source.new_label
/

4 rows merged.
```

The `where` clause is so you only update the rows where the label has actually changed, rather than updating every row in the table.

Also, if this is something you're going to have to recalculate regularly as data is modified, it might be better to use a view that always calculates the label on the fly; though you could then see the 'Y' moving around within an ID when it wouldn't with this method.

Comment: This solution is great, although it took me a while to figure out the logic for each step! Thanks! Yes, I do have a unique ID column (using `sys_guid()`) that I didn't show because I thought it would not help...

Comment: @JeffXi - yes, that isn't needed for the query, though you could use it instead of `order by null` to make it a bit more controlled. You can use that for a merge though, and being able to limit it to only labels that have actually changed will help with a large table.

Comment: Yes, I did as you suggested. It really helps the performance for my large table. Thank you again!